# Cannot retrieve data from Yelp API using jQuery.ajax()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use `jQuery.ajax()` method to retrieve JSON data from Yelp API but its displaying nothing in the console.

The new Yelp authorization just requires headers to be sent as:

```
"Authorization": "Bearer <apikey>"
```

along with the GET request URL with params. Postman is displaying the results but I cannot use it in my API. My code for `.ajax` goes here:

```
var myurl = "https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?term=by-chloe&location=boston";

$.ajax({
  url: myurl,
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  },
  method: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log('success: ' + data);
  }
});
```

Do I need any changes in this one or is there something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that the issue when I tested your script was simply a CORS related one; by appending CORS-anywhere API to the URL I was able to hit your endpoint with your exact same code. Try the code below (just swap your API key)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <title>Ilan's Test</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script>
         var myurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?term=by-chloe&location=boston";

         $.ajax({
            url: myurl,
            headers: {
             'Authorization':'Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
         },
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                console.log('success: '+data);
            }
         });      

      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

// Edit -- Please see the code below for usage on how to use the values returned from the API.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <title>Ilan's Test</title>
   </head>
   <body>

   <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div id="results">

                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
   </div>

      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script>
         var myurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?term=by-chloe&location=boston";

         $.ajax({
            url: myurl,
            headers: {
             'Authorization':'Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
         },
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                // Grab the results from the API JSON return
                var totalresults = data.total;
                // If our results are greater than 0, continue
                if (totalresults > 0){
                    // Display a header on the page with the number of results
                    $('#results').append('<h5>We discovered ' + totalresults + ' results!</h5>');
                    // Itirate through the JSON array of 'businesses' which was returned by the API
                    $.each(data.businesses, function(i, item) {
                        // Store each business's object in a variable
                        var id = item.id;
                        var alias = item.alias;
                        var phone = item.display_phone;
                        var image = item.image_url;
                        var name = item.name;
                        var rating = item.rating;
                        var reviewcount = item.review_count;
                        var address = item.location.address1;
                        var city = item.location.city;
                        var state = item.location.state;
                        var zipcode = item.location.zip_code;
                        // Append our result into our page
                        $('#results').append('<div id="' + id + '" style="margin-top:50px;margin-bottom:50px;"><img src="' + image + '" style="width:200px;height:150px;"><br>We found <b>' + name + '</b> (' + alias + ')<br>Business ID: ' + id + '<br> Located at: ' + address + ' ' + city + ', ' + state + ' ' + zipcode + '<br>The phone number for this business is: ' + phone + '<br>This business has a rating of ' + rating + ' with ' + reviewcount + ' reviews.</div>');
                  });
                } else {
                    // If our results are 0; no businesses were returned by the JSON therefor we display on the page no results were found
                    $('#results').append('<h5>We discovered no results!</h5>');
                }
            }
         });      

      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Remember swap your API key to make the above example work.

CORS is usually enabled server-side; it's a way to prevent unauthorized domains from connecting to and getting data outside of what's allowed; I think if you whitelist the IP address of your server you may still run into issues; I've built many projects which all required bypassing CORS (either using the CORS-Anywhere API, or by making a request asking for JSONP datatype). Cors-Anywhere in general is an open-sourced API you can implement it on your own server or continue using it from the heroku URL; either way you should be able to complete your project.

Please let me know if the above code sample worked for you;
Thanks!
- Ilan

Comment: Hey @Ilan P ,It did work and my console is showing up success and object. I guess its the json object. can you help me further how can I view the response ? Do i need to parse the data ?

Comment: Also is there any other method to overcome CORS other than using the proxy ?

Comment: I had been getting the Too many requests error for using the heroku proxy. So I wanted to know if there was any way to bypass it. Like JSONP ?

Comment: Yelp's API does not offer a CORS solution for AJAX requests (https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-fusion/issues/221) they've indicated they do not support resolutions, ideally you can try and CURL it with PHP and make your AJAX request to your own API; I'm unsure how many requests you are making though (for most solutions using CORS proxy is best in my experience). Jsonp (Json with padding) dataType: jsonp is returning a 401, which means they won't allow it either; your best bets stick with CORSA or try a server-side language.

Comment: Ofcourse. I get it now and its clear too. I understood bout CORS. Thank you @IlanP  i m gonna stick with Corsa.